# Problem with scaling part of the object

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, proportional-editing

Please help me solve the problem.
I need to enlarge a circle, like the example next to it, but when I use scaling, the enlargement is disproportionate.Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, the center of transformation is in active face.

Set *Transform Pivot Point* to *Bounding Box Center* or *Median Point*:

[image]